# Update textbox contained within a different form

Tags: c#, textbox

I have 2 forms. The second form is opened from a method in the first form and I wish to be able to update the textbox that exists within that second form.

Basically I have the following code:

```
    private void sendAllButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendConsoleGUI sendOutGUI = new SendConsoleGUI();
        sendOutGUI.Show();
        sendOutGUI.sendConsoleTextBox.Text = "Test";       
    }
```

When I press the button the second form (SendConsoleGUI form) opens but "Test" is never added to its textbox.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Do you wish to update it dynamically from the Parent form or only when the Child is initially generated?  If you only wish to update the textbox when the Child is initially generated than pass a String as an argument to the form and after InitializeComponents set the textbox to that String you passed.

Comment: Your code should work just fine. The error prorbably lies elsewhere. Set at breakpoint in the other places you update sendConsoleTextBox.Text and see if any fires after the "Test" update.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use invoke method.

```
sendOutGUI.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate { sendOutGUI.sendConsoleTextBox.Text = "Test"; });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public partial class ParentForm : Form
{
    public ParentForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void sendAllButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendConsoleGUI sendOutGUI = new SendConsoleGUI("Test");
        sendOutGUI.Show();     
    }
}

public partial class ChildForm : Form
{
    public ChildForm(string str)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sendConsoleTextBox.Text = str;
    }
}
```

This will work for you if you only wish to update it when the `ChildForm` is initially created.